# C# How to get last 5 variables from an Array?

Tags: c#

I'm creating mobile game in unity, all i need to know is how to get last 5 variables of an Array using `for` or `foreach`?

Comment: You got down votes, because you didn't show what you tried yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a standard for-loop.

```
int[] arr = new int[n];
for (int i = Math.Max(arr.Length - 5, 0); i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]); // do something with `arr[i]`
}
```

With a foreach-loop and Linq (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takelast)

```
foreach (int e in arr.TakeLast(5))
{
    Console.WriteLine(e); // do something with `e`
}
```

The `TakeLast` method is not available in the .NET Framework, you can also use `Skip`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip)

```
foreach (int e in arr.Skip(arr.Length - 5))
{
    Console.WriteLine(e); // do something with `e`
}
```

Comment: TakeLast is not available in the current version(s) of Unity.

Comment: Ok, I have added an example that uses the `Skip` method. I assume that one is available in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ:

```
var last5 = arr.Where((item, index) => index >= arr.Length - 5);
```